# random.choice([x, y, z]) in python, why doesn't the seed change?

Tags: python, random, seeding

```
known_commands = {
    "boo"  : random.choice(["Winter is coming...","SURPRISE!","Mazel tov!"]),
    "xyzzy": xyzzy,
}


def xyzzy(self):

    print random.choice(["Winter is coming...","SURPRISE!","Mazel tov!"])
    return
```

For a class we're making a "baby botnet" in python. So, if I call the command xyzzy or boo, they are implemented every 3 seconds (until I tell them to stop). When I call boo it chooses a random element, but it prints the same random element every 3 seconds. When I call xyzzy it prints a new random element every 3 seconds.

From what I understand that means that the seed does not change for boo, but it does change for xzyyz. My question is, why does the seed change in one case and not the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It makes the choice here

```
"boo"  : random.choice(["Winter is coming...","SURPRISE!","Mazel tov!"]),
```

Since you're calling the function. After this line is evaluated, your dict becomes something like this:

```
known_commands = {
    "boo" : "SURPRISE!",
    "xyzzy" : xyzzy,
}
```

But xyzzy gets a random string every time, since the choice is made in the function every time you call. In order to get a random string for boo everytime, you should make a function or a lambda. It looks like this with a lambda:

```
known_commands = {
    "boo"  : lambda: random.choice(["Winter is coming...","SURPRISE!","Mazel tov!"]),
    "xyzzy": xyzzy,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `boo` key in `known_commands` does not point to a function, it points to the result value of `random.choice`, which was executed only once when the dictionary was constructed. Change it to:

```
"boo": lambda: random.choice(["Winter is coming...", "SURPRISE!", "Mazel tov!"])
```